# Tableviewer edit and save

Tags: swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I am working on a eclipse rcp application where I am using `TableViewer` component on a wizard page. I was able to add editing support to the table columns and was able to save the data on the viewer object. Does this edit get saved to actual data? if yes how can I get this updated data within my application to do further processing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using `org.eclipse.jface.viewers.EditingSupport` to provide cell editors for the table.

The `EditingSupport.setValue` method is responsible for setting the new value in the original object provided by the content provider.

To validate values you will either have to write your own `CellEditor` or use a class derived from one of the existing call editors such as `TextCellEditor` and overriding appropriate methods.

Comment: Greg , yes, I am using the org.eclipse.jface.viewers.EditingSupport . I also have one more requirement to validate the data in edited cells. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Added validation info

Comment: Thanks greg-449. Your suggestion led me to explore few other options. I used the getInput() method on the TableViewer to get the updated data object. Thanks a ton